# Cannot read Regex

Tags: java, regex

Could someone help me with some Regex question?
I have just walked through my Java project using CheckStyle and there is one little message I don't understand:

```
Name 'emf' must match pattern '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'.
```

I am having trouble reading the Regex prerequisite on this variable name. Furthermore I have another variable in the same context with the name em. But CheckStyle didn't mention it though.

Comment: As per a commenter below, to get a complete explanation for why checkstyle is giving this, you should post the relevant variable declarations.  The syntax of the regex is explained below.

Comment: @Mike's right.  That looks like the rule for constant names.  The other name (`em`) is probably for an instance variable.

Comment: private final static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyProgramPU");

I assume the right name would be EMF?

Comment: Yes, "static final" is a constant and should be all upper case (underscores are allowed), regular members should be in camel back with a lower case first character.
Btw, do you really want this to be constant? Could the entity manager factory ever need to change during the VM lifetime?

Comment: I just followed what the NetBeans IDE suggested to me. That's how I came to finalize it. But still, the EntityManagerFactory is only called once at the beginning of the program to create the EntityManager who is alive during the entire program lifetime (as is @ApplicationScoped). Therefore I'd say the EntityManagerFactory has to be final.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Open this [link](http://www.regexper.com/).

Enter your regular expression **(^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$)** in the field provided and click display, there you get the explanation in the graphic format.
Very easy to understand.

EDIT: I totally understand that the link I have specified is for javascript based regex. But, with this, at least you can get the basic understanding of the regex so that you can look back later the slight differences with specific to language you are interested in.

Comment: Didn't knew this site, interesting. Although I would have made a comment and not an anwser.

Comment: Small warning : this uses a JavaScript engine and not a Java one. depending on what you use, you might experience differences.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it makes use of the JavaScript engine, but the slight differences can be understood with the basic understanding of the language specific regex.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to use uppercase letters.

Comment: ... because it's a constant (static final) i guess. CheckStyle is probably trying to enforce Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking down the regex into pieces, we've got:

```
[A-Z]  -- one letter (between A & Z)
[A-Z0-9] -- a letter or number
```

But, adding the `*` after it means that element can appear 0, 1 or multiple times, so:

```
[A-Z0-9]* -- zero, one or more numbers and/or letters.
```

The final piece:

```
(_[A-Z0-9]+)*
```

an element that can appear 0, 1 or multiple times, in which a `_` is followed by at least one letter or number.

Back to your question.  Ignoring case, `emf` would match this, since the `e` would match fall into the first "letter" and the `mf` would fall into the second "0, 1 or more letters and/or numbers".  The last element isn't used.

But if it's case insensitive, then everything fails, because the regex is only allowing uppercase.

Comment: Very good detailed explanation. The only irritating phrase I found was *... `*` after it makes it optional ...*. I would call `?` *optional* but of course you are referring to the fact that `*` could match 0 occurrences.